# Upload request authentication expires by the time the request is sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, afnetworking

We are doing upload requests using AFNetworking, but the problem is we have a short life token (2 hrs) that is needed for the upload request.
When a huge file gets uploaded 1GB or more, by the time the request hits the server the token has expired and the request fails.
Is there is anyway in AFNetworking that we can open the connection with the server (authenticate) and then start streaming the file, just as what happens with the download task when we are receiving a file?

I have tried using all different types of appendPartWith
appendPartWithFileURL
appendPartWithInputStream
appendPartWithFileData

they all have the same behavior from network stand point

```
    {

    ....

NSString *sessionKey = token;
NSString *sha256 = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:fileURL].sha256;
NSString *mimeType = @"application/octet-stream"
unsigned long long filesize = fileSize;
NSTimeInterval timeout = MAX(filesize * 1. / 500000., 30.);

    ....
    request = [self.manager.requestSerializer
        multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                             URLString:URLString
                            parameters:parameters
             constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> _Nonnull formData) {
               [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL
                                          name:@"fileData"
                                      fileName:[fileName urlEncode]
                                      mimeType:mimeType
                                         error:nil];
               [formData appendPartWithFormData:[sessionKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                           name:@"sessionKey"];
             }
                                 error:nil];

    }
    request.timeoutInterval = timeout;
}
return request;

}


    - (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                     fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                     progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress)) uploadProgressBlock
                            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Comment: on server side you should check if streaming is happening dont expire it, how you can even think to expire a token when streaming is happening from a trusted request?

Comment: by the time the request hits the server the token has already expired.
all the time the status of the request is "sending request" by the time the request is "sent" and "waiting for response" the token has already expired

Comment: in that case you should interect with server after every hour if streaming is happening to keep session alive.  and after upload done stop 1 hour interection service too :)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but I was trying to find a fix without having to do backend changes, as that is a bigger project.
What I was looking for is someway I can do the authentication first (like send only the headers that has the auth token) and then start streaming the request body, just as the download request works, but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: you have to work as i said you cannot make sure everyone have a internet connection with good speed so if a person is having speed in 70 to 80 kb's or less you are in trouble in all of low speed cases ... you have to do a mock request to keep session alive its the only thing you can do without doing backend changes.